# How to get multiple outputs of random letters?

Tags: java, string, random, output

I have a program and I need it to ask the user for a word e.g. hello and then ask for a pattern e.g. 2 and then take that word and split up the characters and put random letters between the letters of the word so in this case the users pattern was `3` so `hello` would be outputted as `**h**as**e**rg**l**ty**l**oh**o**`.  So I have the part where I ask the user for a word and I spilt up the characters of the word with `System.out.print(userWord.charAt(0));`

**I just need to know how you would generate random different letters each time between the words characters**.  The section of my code that generates the letters is this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    int cipherchoice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a number!"));

    int z;
    String  mixedarray1 [] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",};
    int x = mixedarray1.length;  // determines the length of mixedarray
    String[] myarray = new String [cipherchoice]; // create a new arracy to be coded

    for (int i = 0; i < cipherchoice; i++)  // loop equal size of coded array
    {  
      z = (int)(Math.random()*x); //  to create a random index value from mixedarray
      myarray[i] = mixedarray1[z]; // assigned myarray a random index value from mixedarray
      System.out.print (myarray [i]); // prints results using print (not println)
    }
}
```

So my output is `System.out.print(myarray [i]);` So how do you get multiple different outputs  (E.g. if the user enters 5 **in another section of code** how would you get 5 different outputs of random letters?

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you have?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with 'different outputs'? never use in the same word the same letters? what if the word is big enough so you need more than 26 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Put your code into a method and call it `n` times. E.g.

```
void printRandomLetter() {
    ... the code you posted ...
}

...
void someOtherMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
        printRandomLetter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please do it quickly and just set the userInput to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the random.org service via HTTP](https://www.random.org/clients/http), by issuing an HTTP GET request to https://www.random.org/strings/?num=10&len=8&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=on&unique=on&format=html&rnd=new, in Java as follows:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.random.org/strings/?num=10&len=8&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=on&unique=on&format=html&rnd=new");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     result += line;
}
rd.close();
```

Your strings will be in result. Exception handling is left as an exercise to the reader.